# How to get desired output using php math functions

Tags: php, math

I have following example in php

```
$available_points = '4409.3';

$convert_currency = number_format($available_points/1000,2);
```

it return me value as **4.41**

& while converting value into points it gives me value **4410** not **4409.3**

```
$available_points = $convert_currency*1000;
```

How can i achieve this with help of php functions or any.

Answer (score 1):

When you are giving the below function:

```
number_format($available_points/1000, 2);
```

You are **truncating** the number to 2 decimal places, thereby the original number is lost in the process. When you are remultiplying it with `1000`, it just takes the value of the truncated number, not the original number. So, a better approach will be, not storing the truncated number by replacing the original number, but on the fly, generating a truncated number, keeping the original number intact.

My best suggestion would be:

```
$available_points = '4409.3';
$original_points = $available_points;
$convert_currency = number_format($available_points/1000, 2);

$available_points = $original_points;
```

Or, if you cannot have duplicate variables for these, you can round them off to 4 decimal places, but still there would be some data loss.

```
$available_points = '4409.3';
$convert_currency = number_format($available_points/1000, 4); 

$available_points = $convert_currency * 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are rounding the precision to 2 decimals. You can do it to 4 decimals if you want to get back your initial value...

```
$available_points = '4409.3';
$convert_currency = number_format($available_points/1000,4); 
// return value : 4.4093

// converting value into points:
$available_points = $convert_currency*1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$available_points = '4409.3';

$convert_currency = number_format($available_points/1000,4);

$available_points = $convert_currency*1000;
```